# GetText together with basic auth

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to fill the userpass below with username and password from labels in my JavaFX program using `userNameLabel.getText()` and `passwordLabel.getText()`

This one doesn't work, only getting `NullPointerException`:

```
// setting authentication
String userpass = **userNameLabel.getText()** + ":" + **passwordLabel.getText()**;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

This one works just fine, without any variables just hard coded username and pw:

```
// setting authentication
String userpass = **"myusername"** + ":" + **"mypassword"**;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

I've also tested with Strings like:

```
String u = userNameLabel.getText(); and just edited the lines above.
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

BR
Andreas

Comment: Which variable is null?

Comment: probably, either `userNameLabel` or `passwordLabel` is `null` considering the code. Are you sure you have initiliased them ?

Comment: Hi! No one of them should be null. I've used the same configuration in another example (but without basicAuth) and it worked just fine.

I usually gets this message when something is null of course, but it should be OK.